# Resize an Array inside an Array

Tags: vba

I have a VBA dictionary with key:value pairs. The key is an animal name and the value is an array of arrays that looks like this: [[kilos eaten], [kilos gained]]. I'm trying to resize the inner arrays so that I can add items to these arrays via a loop. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) indicates that "To resize an array contained in a Variant, you must explicitly declare the Variant variable before attempting to resize its array." I've done this earlier in the code, but I still have a syntax error.

```
            With animalDict
                'Check if the animal is already in the dict
                'If not, create a key:value entry that is equal to (animal name):[[kilos eaten],[kilos gained]]
                If Not .Exists(animalName) Then
                    ReDim kilosEatenArr(0)
                    ReDim kilosGainedArr(0)
                    ReDim outerArr(1)
                    kilosEatenArr(0) = kilosEatenCount
                    kilosGainedArr(0) = kilosGainedCount
                    outerArr(0) = kilosEatenArr
                    outerArr(1) = kilosGainedArr
                    .Add Key:=animalName, Item:=outerArr
                Else
                    outerArr = .Item(animalName)
                    ReDim Preserve outerArr(0)(LBound(outerArr(0)) To UBound(outerArr(0)) + 1) 'Sytnax error here
                    ReDim Preserve outerArr(1)(LBound(outerArr(1)) To UBound(outerArr(1)) + 1) 'Another sytnax error here
                    kilosEatenArr(UBound(kilosEatenArr)) = kilosEatenCount
                    kilosGainedArr(UBound(kilosGainedArr)) = kilosGainedCount
                    outerArr(0) = kilosEatenArr
                    outerArr(1) = kilosGainedArr
                    animalDict(animalName) = outerArr
                End If
            End With
```

Comment: I believe arrays stored as an item in a dictionary become immutable. You need to create a temporary array, copy the value of the dictionary item, redim the temporary, and then load it into the dictionary.

Comment: That's wild. Every time I work in VBA I wish it were more like Python. Thanks.

Comment: You and me both.

Comment: Your problem comes from trying to use arrays.  You should try replacing your arrays with either a collection,  scripting.dictionary or an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

@Warcupine is correct. You have to pull the array out of the dictionary, redim it, set the value for that index and then add it back to the dictionary.

I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
If Not .Exists(animalName) Then
    ReDim kilosEatenArr(0)
    ReDim kilosGainedArr(0)

    kilosEatenArr(0) = kilosEatenCount
    kilosGainedArr(0) = kilosGainedCount

    outerArr = Array(kilosEatenArr(0),kilosGainedArr(0))

    animalDict(animalName) = outerArr   'implict adds are faster

Else 

    outerArr = animalDict(animalName)

    kilosEatenArr = outerArr(0)
    kilosGainedArr = outerArr(1)

    ReDim Preserve kilosEatenArr(LBound(kilosEatenArr) To UBound(kilosEatenArr) + 1)    
    ReDim Preserve kilosGainedArr(LBound(kilosGainedArr) To UBound(kilosGainedArr) + 1)

    kilosEatenArr(UBound(kilosEatenArr)) = kilosEatenCount
    kilosGainedArr(UBound(kilosGainedArr)) = kilosGainedCount

    outerArr = Array(kilosEatenArr, kilosGainedArr)

    animalDict(animalName) = outerArr

End If 


Erase outerArr
Erase kilosEatenArr
Erase kilosGainedArr
```